# DIsplay images using FileField in Django

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a **Django app** which **converts uploaded pdf files into images**. The upload part and conversion part are working fine but I am having **issues on displaying the converted images**. I am using **ModelForms** to upload the pdf files using the **FileField**, converting them into .png and finally displaying them on a new page. If I used an **ImageField**, I won't be able to upload pdf files. So I am using a **FileField** because that is the purpose of the app, to convert pdf to png!

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class UserUploadModel(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'file_uploads')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput
from app1.models import UserUploadModel

class UserUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    

    class Meta:

        model = UserUploadModel
        fields = ['file']
        widgets = {
            'file' : ClearableFileInput(attrs = {'multiple': True}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from app1.forms import UserUploadForm
from app1.models import UserUploadModel
from app1.convert import convert_file
from app1.transfer import move_dir
import os
from project1 import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save()
            f.user = request.user
            f.save()
          
            files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
                        
            f_list = []
            
            if files:
                for i in files:
                    file_instance = UserUploadModel(file = i)
                    file_instance.save()
                    f_list.append(file_instance.file.path)
                
                [convert_file(j) for j in f_list]
                
    
                src_dir = os.getcwd()
                dest_dir = os.path.join(src_dir, 'media/')            
                move_dir(src_dir, dest_dir, '*.png')

            
            return redirect('app1-display')
        
    else:
        
        form = UserUploadForm()
    
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html', {'form' : form})

@login_required
def display(request):
    
    return render(request, 'app1/display.html')
```

**home.html**

```
{%extends "app1/base.html"%}
{%block content%}

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {%csrf_token%}
      {{form.as_p}}
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

{%endblock content%}
```

**EDIT 1:** the display.html is empty because I do not know how to **display images stored in a directory**. If I use **ImageField**, I can use the **url of the image** to display it but I am using **FileField to upload**, convert it to .png and then I store the images in a folder inside the BASE_DIR. Now how do I **display the images stored in a folder in BASE_DIR?**

Also I only want to show the images for the **current logged in user**

**EDIT 2:**
**display.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    {%if user.is_authenticated%}
        <h2>User: {{request.user.username}}</h2>
    {%endif%}

    {%for i in x%}
        <img src={{ i.file.url }}>
    {%endfor%}
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's the problem, you are not sending anything as `context` in `display` view, simply send it and show them.

Comment: Can you share the `app1/display.html` template and also do you want to show all the items or only for logged in user?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I've edited my question to reflect your comment

Comment: Does the images are uploaded in media folder?

Comment: After converting the pdf files, the png files are stored in media folser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work! The reason that duplicate images were being saved in directory was because I was saving the form `form.save()` which will first save the last of the 2 uploaded images (so 1 image saved!) and then I was saving the instance of each and every uploaded file (2 images saved!) which results in 3 images! Hence I changed my view to this:-

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from app1.models import UserUploadModel
from app1.forms import UserUploadForm
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        
        form = UserUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        
        if form.is_valid():            
            files = request.FILES.getlist('file')                
                
            if files:
                for i in files:
                    file_instance = UserUploadModel(file = i, user = request.user)
                    file_instance.save()
            
        return redirect('app1-display')
    
    else:
        
        form = UserUploadForm()
    
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html', {'form' : form})


def display(request):
    
    x = UserUploadModel.objects.filter(user = request.user)

    context = {
        'x' : x
        }
    
    return render(request, 'app1/display.html', context)
```

**display.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    {%if user.is_authenticated%}
        <h2>User: {{request.user.username}}</h2>
    {%endif%}

    {%if x%}
        {%for i in x%}
            <img src={{ i.file.url }}>
        {%endfor%}
    {%endif%}
</body>
</html>
```

This will allow user to upload multiple images and display all of them!
Thanks to @Sunderam Dubey for helping me out with the `views.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You should first send all the images of current logged in user in the context then display it using `.url` in `img` tag.

views.py:

```py
@login_required
def display(request):
    user_uploads=UserUploadModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context={"user_uploads":user_uploads}
    
    return render(request, 'app1/display.html', context)
```

app1/display.html:

```html
<body>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <h2>User : {{request.user.username}}</h2>
    {% endif %}
    <br><br>

    {% for user_upload in user_uploads %}
        <img src="{{user_upload.file.url}}" width='300px'>
        <br><br>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

> **Note:** Models in Django doesn't require model to be the suffix, so you may write the model name as `UserUpload` instead of <s>`UserUploadModel`</s>.

> Additionally, I'd suggest to maintain proper gap between template tags such as it should be `{% csrf_token %}` not <s>`{%csrf_token%}`</s> and so on.

Comment: What if my images are stored inside a folder which is inside the media folder?

Comment: @spectre The solution will also work for that. Have you tried?

Comment: @spectre  Also press `Ctrl+u` and see the source in the img tag, click on that, you'll be redirected to image, if the path is correct.

Comment: I tried but if I upload 2 files, it only displays one of them

Comment: @spectre Share your actual tempate in question? Sorry I made a typo, it is `user_uploads` not `user_upload` in view.

Comment: Shared! Yeah I noticed that but I am using `x` instead of `user_uploads`. Another weird thing that is happening is that If I upload one file, it displays 2 duplicated images. I mean it is displaying 2 same images. In the media folder also it is saving 2 duplicates of the same file